# How to convert list of string in key value pair json string response?

Tags: c#

Below is my list of string :

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>(new string[] { "element1", "element2", "element3" });
```

Now i want to return above list in the form of below output to web service :

```
{
 "element1" : "",
 "element2" : "",
 "element3" : "",
}
```

I want to display output like below on my website :

```
{
 "element1" : "",
 "element2" : "",
 "element3" : "",
}
```

This is how i am doing right now :

```
 string output = "{" + Environment.NewLine;
            foreach (var item in myList)
            {
                output += $"\"{item}\" : \"\"," + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            output = output.Remove(output.Length - 1) + "}";
```

But when i will have 40-50 records then my loop will run for 40-50 times which i am trying to avoid.

I even tried to use this :

```
 string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList);
```

But above is not giving exact output format which i want.

Can anybody please suggest me any better way to do this which will avoid forloop and reduce the code to produce the expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do what you want it to:

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                    mylist.ToDictionary(key => key, v => string.Empty));
```

Using `ToDictionary()` we create a `Dictionary<T1, T2>` (in your case `Dictionary<string, string>`) from your list.  We're making the `Key` equal to the item in the list, and the `Value` just an empty string.

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HjWBpc)

**EDIT**
If you want the indented formatting, pass a second parameter to SerializeObject:

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                    mylist.ToDictionary(key => key, v => string.Empty)
                    Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but i want every element on new line.see my expected output in which first record is on new line after first curely bracket and last curly bracket is also on new line

Comment: This worked as expected.thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this.Appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use .NET built-in class without the need to any third-party library:
**using JavaScriptSerializer**

```
var list = new List<string>() { "element1", "element2", "element3" };
var dic = list.ToDictionary(k => k, v => string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dic));
```

[image]

**Note**
Don't forget to add `System.Web.Extensions` as a reference to your project

Comment: OP is _already_ using JSON.NET, it says so right in their post.  Without question JSON.NET is better than the built in class.

Comment: I didn't notice he's using JSON.NET; however, using JavaScriptSerializer is still a choice if a preference is not to use external libraries.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this.Appreciated :)

Comment: FYI: Microsoft's [own documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) tells you to use Json.NET for JSON serialization/deserialization